# VS2010, MSDeploy and declaration of parameters

Tags: visual-studio-2010, deployment, msdeploy

I'm trying to deploy an ASP.NET MVC 2 app using MsDeploy. I use VS2010 to generate the package as a ZIP. Inside that ZIP is a `parameters.xml` file that declares the parameters that I can set.

I want to be able to set more parameters, using the auto-generated `deploy.cmd` file like this:

```
MySite.deploy.cmd 
    "-setParam:name='IIS Web Application Name',value=MySite" 
    "-setParam:name=IisVirtualDirectoryPhysicalPath,value=C:\inetpub\MySite" 
    "-setParam:name=httpBinding,value=*:80:www.mysite.dk"
```

That works fine, except for the `httpBinding param`. That is because that parameter is not declared inside the `parameters.xml` file that is added to the ZIP container.

I could go and add that parameter declaration manually, but isn't there a way to do it from the command line and have it declare parameters I have in another XML file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you saying that the value param was not declared when the package was created? If so then I think you would have to add it. Either manually or you can use the -setParam switch and sync the package from and to itself. If you use -setParam with a name which was never declared as a param to begin with I'm pretty sure that value is just ignored.

Comment: Actually, if you use a param that was not previously declared, msdeploy will fail, e.g. `msdeploy.exe [...] -setParam:a=b` yields `Error: Unrecognized argument 'a'. Error count: 1.` I think this is not very reasonable on msdeploy's part, but this is the way it is now.

Answer (score 1):

I'm only just looking at this, but is the section on [MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd569084%28v=WS.10%29.aspx) about the matching of `declareParam` with `setParam` the way to go ?

I'm using MsDeploy to update my deployment zip following the idea in this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023762/set-application-pool-for-package-using-msdeploy) post

*Apologies if I'm completely off on this*