# Set Application Pool for package using MSDeploy

Tags: iis-7, msdeploy, application-pool

I am deploying a website using MSDeploy so using something like the below code.

```
"%ProgramFiles%\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy\msdeploy.exe" 
     -verb:sync
     -source:package=WebAppServer.zip 
     -dest:Auto 
     -setParamFile="was_params.xml" 
     -verbose 
          >  webappserversync.log
```

Is there anyway to set the application pool ? I want to do this from the command line and not set it in a manifest or anything like that.

Shouldn't matter but this is in IIS7.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When you generate your package, you need to have an entry in the parameters.xml file for setting the Application Pool.  When deploying, you either include a value for that in your setParameters.xml file, or use -setParam from the command line.

Here is the command I used to grab a site, which generated the proper parameters.xml file ...

```
msdeploy.exe 
  -verb:sync -source:appHostConfig="Default Web Site" 
  -enableLink:AppPoolExtension 
  -dest:package=site.zip 
  -declareParam:name="Application Pool",
       defaultValue="Default Web Site",
       description="Application pool for this site",
       kind=DeploymentObjectAttribute,
       scope=appHostConfig,
       match="application/@applicationPool"
```

And to install this site from the command line, this ...

```
msdeploy.exe 
    -verb:sync 
    -dest:appHostConfig="MagicSite" 
    -enableLink:AppPoolExtension 
    -source:package=site.zip 
    -setParam:"Application Pool"="MagicPool"
```

Dig around in the parameters.xml file to see the entry necessary.  And if you prefer, that `-setParam` entry can exist in your `params.xml` file instead.

Comment: blowed if I can get this to work. Scripting out the app pool just fine, but setting that parameter when I call msdeploy seems to make no difference.

Comment: I seem to get the following error when I try this:
`Error: Source (sitemanifest) and destination (appHostConfig) are not compatible for the given operation.`

Comment: I get this `Error: Using a 64-bit source and a 32-bit destination with provider appHostConfig is not supported.`

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this answer:

[Set application pool with MSDeploy and TFS 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4462001/set-application-pool-with-msdeploy-and-tfs-2010/5235921#5235921)

Basically, you create a batch file with an adsutil script to set the app pool, and then you call MSDeploy to run that batch file on the target computer.

Comment: ...to create the app pool. But how to target it for the website?