# vs2010 web application package deploy.cmd - specify application pool

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, iis

I am attempting to deploy a web application to IIS using a web application package. When I try to use the web deploy command line to run my application.deploy.cmd I get an error saying that my managed runtime version is version 2 and not version 4 as my application requires.

I understand that I must be using an application pool which is configured to use ASP.NET 4.0 and I have an application pool which is configured to use ASP.NET 4.0.

My question is how do I tell the Web Deploy Command Line tool which application pool to use when I run my application.deploy.cmd?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this. Will work if you are asking about MSDeploy

[Set Application Pool for package using MSDeploy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023762/set-application-pool-for-package-using-msdeploy)

Command :

```
msdeploy.exe 
  -verb:sync -source:appHostConfig="Default Web Site" 
  -enableLink:AppPoolExtension 
  -dest:package=site.zip 
  -declareParam:name="Application Pool",
       defaultValue="Default Web Site",
       description="Application pool for this site",
       kind=DeploymentObjectAttribute,
       scope=appHostConfig,
       match="application/@applicationPool
```