# .net WebDeploy is there any way to run command/script on the target machine after deploy

Tags: webdeploy, webdeploy-3.5

I have and .net/angular2 application, I'm publishing with WebDeploy.
But when the publish finish I wanna run some command on the target machine like

```
npm install
npm run tsc
```

There is a way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use the `postSync` argument:

```
msdeploy -verb:sync -source:contentPath="C:\Test1" -dest:contentPath="C:\Test2" -postSync:runcommand="c:\MyBatchFile.bat"
```

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd569089(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: Hi @chief7, can this command be added to the .pubxml file when publishing, instead of having to publish via command-line?