# Set Application Pool in IIS Deployment with Azure Release Pipeline

Tags: iis, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, msdeploy, application-pool

I'm deploying an IIS Web App with IIS Web App Deploy Task in Azure DevOps Release Pipeline. This works good but don't set the correct application pool. I'm trying it with set a Parameter in Parameters.xml or as -setParam to the Task. But this doesn't change anything. The googled Solutions didn't help. How can I manipulate the Application Pool during deployment? Thanks.

**EDIT**

In reference to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4160940/2241653) I configured the parameters.xml and pipeline like this.
 (appHostConfig instead of appPoolConfig hadn't changed anything)

`parameters.xml`

```
<parameters>
    <parameter name="Parameter 1" description="Full site path where you want to install your application (for example, Default Web Site/Application)." defaultValue="Default Web Site/MyApplication" tags="IisApp">
        <parameterEntry kind="ProviderPath" scope="iisApp" match="Default\ Web\ Site/MyApplication" />
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="Parameter 2" description="Enter the name of the application pool." defaultValue="MyAppPool" tags="AppPoolConfig">
        <parameterEntry kind="ProviderPath" scope="appPoolConfig" match="MyAppPool" />
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="IIS Web Application Name" description="Enter the name of the website." defaultValue="MyApplication" tags="IisApp" />
    <parameter name="Application Pool" description="Enter the name of the application pool." defaultValue="MyAppPool" tags="AppPoolConfig" />
</parameters>
```

Set the website in IIS Web App Deploy Task
 (results to `-setParam:name='IIS Web Application Name',value='Default Web Site/MyApplication'`)

[image: Website / Application]

Set the Application Pool parameter in IIS Web App Deploy Task

[image: Application Name]

Answer (score 1):

> Set Application Pool in IIS Deployment with Azure Release Pipeline

Since you do not share how did you set the Parameter in `Parameters.xml`and `-setParam` to the Task, I am not sure if you correct set the Parameter.

You could check [this](https://forums.iis.net/t/1195472.aspx) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023762/set-application-pool-for-package-using-msdeploy) thread for some more info.

Anyway, for azure devops, there is an option **Application Pool** for the task `IIS Web App deployment`, which we could set the Application Pool:

[image]

Besides, the `IIS Web App deployment` is currently deprecated, MS recommends the task [WinRM - IIS Web App Management](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-extensions/blob/master/Extensions/IISWebAppDeploy/Src/Tasks/IISWebAppMgmt/IISWebAppMgmtV1/README_IISAppMgmt.md).

**Update:**

There is an option `Configuration type`, select `IIS Website`:

[image]

Please check [this document](https://medium.com/@taithienbo/build-and-deploy-an-asp-net-core-app-running-on-iis-using-azure-pipelines-e675041f62d4) for some more details.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I edited the post how the parameters.xml and the pipeline are configured. I've already seen the IIS App Management Task. In this I have to set all parameters like pipeline mode or credentials in every pipeline which will release a website with this application pool (and this will be a lot). If this would be the best option then I would do this and set this with variable group parameters. But I would prefer something where I have only to set the Application Pool name without all other pool settings.

Comment: @mburm, You could create a task group for the IIS App Management Task, so that we do not need to set all parameters in every pipeline one by one.

Comment: The Task Groups are a great idea and this makes a lot of things easier in our deployment process. The IIS App Management Task works and I can create an application pool should it not exists. But farther it doesn't work with the binding to the application. There I get again the default pool.

Comment: @mburm, Sorry i misunderstood your question, if you want to binding the application pool to the application, you could select the `IIS Website` in the `Configuration type`, then enable the checkbox **Create or update app pool**. Check if my update answer give any helps. Have a nice day :).

Comment: @mburm, Any update for this issue? Have you resolved this issue? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Comment: I am having the same problem. It will create the missing application pool in IIS, but it will not change the Web site to use the new or existing app pool. The Release Pipeline does not give an error message either; it just doesn't alter the app pool setting on the server. I also grabbed the appcmd.exe command from the Release log and ran it myself on the server. Again, it completed without an error but did not change the app pool setting of the site.

Answer (score 0):

Create inline PowerShell Script task after Web App Deploy with:

```
c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\AppCmd.exe set app /app.name:"APPLICATIONNAMEHERE" /applicationpool:"APPLICATIONPOOLNAMEHERE"
```

to assign the application pool created above.

Comment: I received an error message "ERROR ( message:Must use exact identifer for APP object with verb SET. )"

Answer (score 0):

This bug is still present in the Azure Pipelines "IIS web app manage" step, in December 2023.

- It creates the App Pool.
- It creates the empty IIS website.
- But it *doesn't* link the website to the App Pool (sigh.)

The fix, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68414293/391605) is to add a line like this to the *Advanced\Additional appcmd.exe commands* section:

```
set site /site.name:"$(WebsiteName)" -[path='/'].applicationPool:"$(YourAppPoolName)"
```

[image]

(A day later..)

Today, I noticed that, in the "IIS web app manage" step, if your App Pool already exists, and you specify a new Physical Path for your IIS website..

- it *will* create that folder...
- "IIS web app deploy" *will* deploy your files to this folder...
- but the IIS website will not be updated to point at this
  folder.

Once again, you can use "`set site`" to fix this.  (Sigh.)

```
set site /site.name:"$(WebsiteName)" 
-[path='/'].applicationPool:"$(YourAppPoolName)" 
-[path='/'].virtualDirectory[path='/'].physicalPath:"D:\SomeFolderOrOther"
```

Btw, in my "IIS web app deploy" page, I have the Action set to "Create or Update", and under IIS Website, I have "Create or update app pool" ticked.