# DevOps Release Pipeline is not setting an IIS Web Site's Application Pool

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

We have a DevOps Release Pipeline, IIS Deployment task that is not setting the Web site's Application Pool on the server to the new name that has been specified in the "Deployment process" properties in DevOps.

The app pool name is correctly specified here, and the Release Pipeline ***does*** create the app pool if it doesn't exist.

[image]

And the app pool name is also correctly displayed here.

[image]

In the IIS Web App Manage logs, the Web Site name is correct, and the app pool name displayed in each of these spots are all correct, but notice there are no error messages here. I tried executing the same "set site" command on the command line on the server myself, and again, it executed without an error message, but does not change the site's application pool.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After testing the appcmd.exe command-line parameters in the IIS Web App Manage task, I discovered that DevOps never sends the parameter to change a Web site's application pool to the name specified in the Release Pipeline Settings. This custom parameter below will set the app pool during release.

```
set site /site.name:"$(Parameters.WebsiteName)" -[path='/'].applicationPool:"$(Parameters.AppPoolNameForWebsite)"
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not allowed to leave a comment to just say "Thank You!!!" for this tip... so I'll just say that this bug is still present in Azure Pipelines in Dec 2023, and this brilliant "set site" command fixes it beautifully.